# Closing OT questions that belong on other SE Sites

Tags: discussion, support

So we got [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8767/how-to-invertibly-transcript-german-umlauts-in-ascii?noredirect=1#comment23005_8767) about transcribing umlauts to non-umlauts and back.

this question in my opinion belongs to SO.

**Why?**
Because this is "simply": how can i encode a file with non-ASCII signs to ASCII and back, an get the same content again. Even though the question specifically asked for umlauts, this is not a german-only problem.
In French for example: ``´^`these can be put above every`aeiou`.

I then wanted to flag this question as OT to migrate it to SO, (if enough people had agreed), and found: when going through the close reasons, i can only chose this meta-site.

**What happened to the box with the custom SE-Site?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-moderator users of a site possible migration paths are limited to avoid migrating poor question to random sites. For us we only have a migration path to our own Meta.

In case we do have a question that **clearly** belongs to another site we may flag the question for moderator attention. Moderators can migrate questions to all other sites but they are encouraged to ask the community there whether they want this question or not. Only then a migration will eventually take place provided it was not an old question.

See also the following SE network wide relevant posts on this topic:

- [Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)
- [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)
- [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators)
- [When voting to migrate an off-topic question, why is the list of sites limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited)
- [Closing/Migrating question instructions/guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/closing-migrating-question-instructions-guidance)

The case of the qestion above is clearly not on topic for Stack Overflow, as it primarily does not ask for a programmatical appproach to convert a file with umlauts but rather on how to make it still readable and avoid wrong replacements in case of exceptions. These questions are a matter of the German language, not of programming.

Therefore any migration request will have to be declined until the question itself was edited to meet requirements to be on topic on another site.

Comment: This procedure is pretty surprising if there is a checkbutton in the dialog but no explanation and no link to this discussion here.